# linux run script at startup centos

Tags: node.js, linux, centos7

i have nodejs App i want 
 run script at startup centos

my script.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/mb/Desktop/Voip
gulp
```

my Executing Commands and Scripts at Reboot & Startup in Centos 7 is

```
crontab -e

@reboot sh /home/mb/Desktop/script.sh
```

does not work

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to edit `/etc/rc.local` :

```
/bin/sh /home/mb/Desktop/script.sh &
```

or try to debug your cron :

```
crontab -e

@reboot /bin/sh /home/mb/Desktop/script.sh &>/tmp/debug
```

Then, `cat /tmp/debug`

Comment: tnx I add export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin  To the script.sh